# Is there anyway to show the users who submitted the contact form in shopify?

Tags: shopify

Help if it is possible to show contact form submits in shopify. I know it is sent to the admin email but I want to see it in tabular view or even get via contact form submits API.

Answer (score 0):

Without an use of some kind of app there is no way to achieve this with standard Liquid logic.

So the short answer is no.